# How to install a PostgreSQL terminal client using microdnf install?

Tags: linux, postgresql, keycloak, dnf

What PostgreSQL clients are available through microdnf install?
I'm trying to install a client via my Dockerfile.

I've tried multiple commands I've seen recommended and several guesses, but none of them worked for me:

```
microdnf install -y postgresql-client
microdnf install -y postgresql
microdnf install -y psql
etc.
```

Image being used:
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

```
sh-4.4$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.3 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.3"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.3:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.3"
```

PS = Is there a website I can go to to see the full list of packages available?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue, but with `maven` docker image (it based on OracleLinux 8).

### Oracle Linux 8 & Postgresql13 Client

It was extremely unusual to install postgresql client on it, so, let's consider my steps:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/
   Select RHEL 8 and receive the rpm package link
2. Install it manually with `rpm`

```sh
microdnf install -y wget
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm -O /tmp/pg_repo.rpm
rpm -i /tmp/pg_repo.rpm
```

3. Determine that there is no `postgresql13` package. Click on the [direct download](https://yum.postgresql.org/rpmchart/) link and select RHEL 8: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/13/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/
4. Download `postgresql13-13.x.x...` package (latest)

```sh
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/13/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/postgresql13-13.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm -O /tmp/pgql.rpm
```

Dependency list for that rpm:

```
libicu is needed by postgresql13-13.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
        libpq.so.5()(64bit) is needed by postgresql13-13.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
        postgresql13-libs(x86-64) = 13.3-2PGDG.rhel8 is needed by postgresql13-13.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
        systemd is needed by postgresql13-13.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
        systemd-sysv is needed by postgresql13-13.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
```

5. Install dependencies

```sh
microdnf install -y systemd postgresql13-libs libicu
```

6. Finally, install the client

```sh
rpm -i /tmp/pgql.rpm
```

Now you can clear the cache and test the client, e.g. `pg_dump` command.

Result Dockerfile command:

```
RUN microdnf install -y wget && \
    wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm -O /tmp/pg_repo.rpm && \
    rpm -i /tmp/pg_repo.rpm && \
    microdnf install -y systemd postgresql13-libs libicu && \
    wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/13/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/postgresql13-13.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm -O /tmp/pgql.rpm && \
    rpm -i /tmp/pgql.rpm && \
    rm -f /tmp/pg_repo.rpm /tmp/pgql.rpm && \
    microdnf remove -y wget
```

### RHEL 8 & Postgresql13 Client (your case)

Now let's consider your case, image `jboss/keycloak:14.0.0` based on RHEL 8.

Caveat: If you receive error message `error: Failed to create: /var/cache/yum/metadata`, run as root user and than switch user back to jboss.

All steps and Dockerfile commands are the same.

Please, let me know if there are any mistakes or something is not well-described.

Comment: @Tliak - I tried several ways of running as root (sudo & the like), but commands didn't exist. How would I execute as root in a standard keycloak container.

Comment: add the `--user root` to your `docker exec` command

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me on with a Dockerfile based on openjdk:15.

```
FROM openjdk:15.0.1-oracle
...
RUN microdnf update
RUN microdnf module enable postgresql:13
RUN microdnf install postgresql.x86_64
```

Comment: I'm not using that image.